# Transfer issue an IOS app from one developer account to another. If I delete from one account and create another, update possible?

Tags: ios, iphone

I have an IOS app and bundle id with "org.application.ios". I wanted to transfer an app to another account. There is an issue with plugins used so unable to transfer the same.

So planning to delete from one developer account and create the app with same name and bundle id. Is it possible that existing users will get update for the new app uploaded.

#ios #developer.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't re-use the bundle id from another account.

As per [App Store Connect help](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev28d17ed35)

> If you remove an app, you will lose ownership of the app name. Removed
> apps can only be restored if the name is not currently in use by
> another developer account. In addition, the SKU can’t be reused in the
> same organization and if you’ve uploaded a build, your bundle ID can’t
> be reused.

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need to contact Apple. If you want the *same* app (so that updates work) apple must move the app to another developer account, you can’t do that yourself.